# What is this amber like substance on capacitor and inductor?

Tags: pcb-design, wireless, materials, router

[image]

#### What is the mysterious substance on the inductor and (failed) capacitor?

#### What is its purpose, and how do I replace the failed capacitor with it there?

The substance is hard and translucent, but I can make a very small impression with my finger nail.

This comes from a Belkin n-wireless router I am trying to fix, if that helps.

---

## Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems some kind of epoxy. Maybe they secure the tall components this way. If this is the case, be careful removing it, it may take out traces from pcb or small components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are referring to is simply a magnificent blob of hot glue or more colloquially known as "hot-snot" to prevent the capacitor from breaking off with excessive vibration.

If you want to remove it, use a heat gun on a very low setting, if it is indeed hot glue it should allow you to scrape it off. If its epoxy you have to nip at it to try and scrape enough off to allow you to remove the bad capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like some sort of glue, used to fix the components firmly to the board. You should be able to remove the capacitor by heating the glue with a hot-air gun and when warm, try break the seal between the capacitior and coil. Then de-solder the capacitor and remove.

Answer (score 0):

The translucent material on these components is there to provide mechanical stability and serves no electronic purpose.
It is unlikely that the inductor has failed. You should be careful that its windings remain insulated from one another - their copper is coated with an insulating enamel to keep each turn insulated from its neighboring turns.
Your photo shows unclearly how firmly the translucent material holds the electrolytic capacitor. It is likely soldered to the board with two leads. These should be de-soldered, and all solder sucked away (not an easy job). You might be able to slice through its black plastic sleeve to the aluminum casing. It is possible that the translucent material only has a hold of the capacitor by its sleeve. Try to keep the aluminum casing intact - this capacitor contains volatile material that should not contaminate you, or the board's components.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see anything amber on the capacitor.

The amber color of the inductor is due to the insulation of the wire, and possibly a little of the copper shining thru this insulation.  This type of insulation is called *enamel coated*, and is common where physical space is important.  Wire specifically sold for this kind of application is often referred to as *magnet wire*.

Enamel coating as insulation is thin and fairly heat tolerant.  Both these properties are useful in a magnetic winding.

Comment: Look closely at the picture. There is a puddle of melted -something- which has accumulated around the base of the inductor. It looks as if the inductor got really hot. Either that or the inductor was installed using a dollop of something like urethane to mechanically keep it in place.

Comment: @What: I thought that was a shadow below the inductor due to the lighting coming from the top left of the picture.  We really need a proper picture to do anything more than guess.